# Loop XPATH in PHP trought results

Tags: php

I can't understand how to loop trough result with XPATH.

I've a scenario like:

```
$html = '<div><input type="text" class="input" value="A"><input type="text" class="input" value="B"></div>';
```

I need to get the value of the first input found (in my case: **A**), using their class name.

I tried:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$r = $xpath->query("//input[@class='input']");

foreach ( $r as $r2 ) {
    echo $r2->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

But I get always error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::item()`

Comment: `$r = $xpath->query("//input[@class='input']/@value"); echo $r->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: @splash58 thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

For HTML in php i recomend using a library for html dome , is Easier that using html as xml, and fastest than using DOM:HTML native

Look foward to this library: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

This make html working much more easier.

Regarding exatly your question,  did you try ChildNodes and then item(0) ? you shoud probably validate your html so its a valid xml.

Hope it helps.